# How to open file upload dialog without on click event in reactJS or javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to open file upload dialog without on click event in reactJS or javascript
What I want to achieve is:
open file upload dialog without on click event in reactJS or javascript

```
const buttonClick = (e) => {
    const el3 = fileUpload.current;
    if ("isTrusted" in e) {
        if (e.isTrusted) {
            el3.click();
        } else {
            el3.click();
    }
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    const el3 = fileUpload.current;
    el3.click();
    const el2 = myContainer.current;
    
    const mouseClickEvents = ['pointerdown', 'click', 'pointerup'];
    function simulateMouseClick(element) {
        mouseClickEvents.forEach(mouseEventType =>
            element.dispatchEvent(
                new PointerEvent(mouseEventType,
                    {
                        pointerId: 1,
                        bubbles: true,
                        cancelable: true,
                        pointerType: "mouse",
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        isPrimary: true,
                        isTrusted: true
                    })
            )
        );
    }
    simulateMouseClick(el2);
}, []);
```

Comment: Probably not going to happen due to security reasons. You wouldn't want a random site to be able to open a file upload dialog without a prompt.

Comment: Yes, trying a much simpler version that just uses jQuery's `.trigger('click')`, in Chrome gives me the following in console: _"File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation."_

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @AKX But I did not understand the reason properly can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: @CBroe Yes, even i was getting the same.

Comment: Browser vendors have decided that it would be too annoying to have random sites pop this up without the user actually requesting it, and so they decided to block it.

Comment: So what is the solution for this? I need a input file dialog on load of webpage and wanted to upload .csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a input file dialog on load of webpage and wanted to upload .csv file

That simply won't happen.

For security reasons, opening a file chooser requires a real, genuine user interaction.

> So what is the solution for this?

Change your requirements from "on load of webpage" to "on click of button".